# Поймать событие CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Здравствуйте!

Я использую CKEditor для редактирования контента в окне, которое вызывается посредством модуля Modal в Twitter Bootstrap. Выглядит это примерно так: http://f4.s.qip.ru/hjWejzPm.png

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь вставить ссылку, то в новом всплывающем окне не получается установить фокус в текстовое поле для ввода - т.е. я кликаю, но ничего не происходит: http://f1.s.qip.ru/hjWejzPn.png

Методом проб и ошибок я выяснил, что это происходит из-за Бутстраповского окна. Т.е. если его вручную скрыть в консоли (display: none), то фокус нормально устанавливается и вообще нет никаких проблем.

Я думал, что проблема в z-index, но так и не смог найти ее источник, поэтому решил поступать по-другому. При клике на иконку для вставки ссылки модальное окно Бутстрапа будет скрываться (display: none), а после окончания всех операций - снова отображаться.

Вопрос в следующем - как поймать событие, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку добавления ссылки: http://f1.s.qip.ru/hjWejzPo.png

В документации копался, плодов это не принесло, хотя не исключаю, что просто упустил нужную информацию.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function () {
    var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById('cke_56');
    element.on('click', function () {
        console.log(3123123);
    });
});
```

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.event.html

http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html